# Can we use custom settings in SOQL queries?

Tags: apex, soql, class, customsetting, for

I need to use run a query based on the value in custom settings. Delete_Lookup__c is my custom settings. I need to change the output of query based on the values in custom settings.

```
    global class CustomHelperClass {
        public static void deleteDealPipeline(List<Id> accnts){
           system.debug('Account Trigger  '+accnts);
           List<Delete_Lookup__c> lookup =Delete_Lookup__c.getAll().values();
           for(Delete_Lookup__c l : lookup){
                List<Deal_Pipeline__c> dealPipelines = [SELECT Id, Name FROM l.API_Value__c where l.Relationship__c.Id IN :accnts];
                system.debug('SOQL Account  '+dealPipelines);
                delete dealPipeLines; 
           }
    
        }
    }
```

I'm getting an error "Invalid type: Schema.API_Value__c" in the SOQL query. Can anyone help me to understand the issue here?

Comment: Apart from getting an answer to your question, you should take some time to review [Apex Design Best Practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/wiki/apex_code_best_practices) and move your SOQL & DML outside of your for loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming I understand your code correctly, you need a dynamic query for this, since you're trying to use a variable in the FROM clause:

```
List<sObject> childRecords = Database.query(
  'SELECT Id FROM '+
  l.API_Value__c+
  ' where '+
  l.Relationship__c+
  ' IN :accnts'
);
delete childRecords;
```

Comment: Thanks alot. It is working